# Convert associative array values in two normal array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Access Control
            [editable] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] =>  CCTV
            [editable] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Fire Alarm
            [editable] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Intrusion Alarm System
            [editable] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Home Automation
            [editable] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => Security Equipments
            [editable] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => Audio Video
            [editable] => 0
        )

)
```

From this i want to create two new arrays
one for store `id` and next is for store `name`.
I've tried `array_values` method but it will returns the same array

Comment: use `array_column` to achieve this

Comment: Thanks its worked:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `array_column` can do what you want. Let your array name is `$arr`.

```
$id = array_column($arr, "id");
$name = array_column($arr, "name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `array_column` doesn't works on PHP < 5.5. If your PHP version is >= 5.3, you can use this approach:

```
$ids = array_map(function($element) {
  return $element['id'];
}, $arr);

$names = array_map(function($element) {
  return $element['name'];
}, $arr);
```